# Is it correct to connect upper case cursive letters to lower case ones?

Tags: writing

https://www.logicofenglish.com/blog/44-handwriting/525-connecting-uppercase-cursive-letters

I just love English cursive alphabets and I often use them in my handwriting. I never connect upper-case cursive letters to lower-case ones. But on the above link there are some examples of connecting them. is that writing style correct or not?

Comment: Why not? In all cursive writing languages I know, the Uppercase initial letter is connected to the next letter

Comment: There are many different styles of cursive writing, not just one.  There is no single correct way of doing it - though of course if you are learning a particular style, you should arguably follow that style's conventions, but in practice most writers develop their own individual style that deviates to a greater or lesser extent from what they were originally taught.

Comment: What are the most standard styles of English cursive writing? What are their names?How can I find them?

Comment: D'Nealian is very common ( http://www.dnealian.com/lessons.html ).  The style I was taught was somewhat similar to Barchowsky ( http://www.bfhhandwriting.com/about ).